# How to insert Excel sheet file into SQL Server database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have an Excel sheet with more than 1000 records with customer details such as `name`, `tele`, `address` ...etc.  and I want to know if I can save this sheet into a SQL Server database without inserting these records one by one from an `aspx` page, as I will have table in the database with customer details.

Comment: If I understand you correctly couldnt you store it as a byte stream in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SSMS's Import Data option, and use Excel as a data source and the table as the destination. This is a "run once" option. The second option, if you have to run this frequently, is to create an SSIS package for the import.